# Different sound quality through mixer output than in mixer.

Tags: location-recording, recorder-mixer, camera

Hi guys,

I own an SQN 4-s early series mixer. I have been experimenting with the mixer prior to a shoot where I will be using the mixer to send audio to the camera. Basically I am using the mixer with a boom and two Radio mics on channels 1 and 2+3 respectively.

Using the tails I am sending my output into my 702 and monitoring the signal on return to the mixer. Now, I have set up the line up tone at -20d and continue to monitor the signal that is returning from my 702. (In other words, the 702 is replacing the camera for experimentation purposes). However, as I switch from monitoring the return feed from the 702 and the actual input into the SQN mixer the two signals sound quite dramatically different. The return feed from the 702 is thin and lacks the bass in the signal I am getting monitoring the signal in the mixer.

I have checked all high-pass filters, headphone volumes, limiters etc on both devices.

My suspicion is that the outputs on the old SQN are simply not very good. Does anyone else have experience of this? It seems odd the outputs on the tail are not of great quality as this is obviously the main purpose of the mixer.

Any help much appreciated :)

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. Yep i'm using it with a multipin out in this case, I get the same kind of quality on the XLR outs too. A few people have suggested phase too, but I notice the effect on just one channel. Having played around a little more it's perhaps not just as dramatic as I first thought. I've been switching back between the 702 and the SQN and perhaps it is more of a question of taste between these two devices sounds? I'll try and record an input from each and post them up here soon. Thanks again guys.

Comment: have someone take a look at it. this is strange behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried monitoring directly from the headphone output of your 702? Bear in mind that most headphone output are unbalanced signals, and depending on the wiring of your return cable, that may be causing some phase issues.

On the other hand, I have the same problem whenever I take a return and run it through a separate headphone amp instead of the returns of my SD mixers. Its a major difference like what you have described and I never really figured out why.

Answer (score 1):

Curious, this type of mixer is sturdy and doesn't start acting up suddenly (in my experience at least).
What do you mean with 'tails' is that the multipin output on your mixer, with the screw on plug? If so, have you tested the XLR outputs? How do they sound? Also can you listen to both outputs without the SD702 in between?

Answer (score 1):

If the bass is lacking, then it sounds like there's a phase issue, i.e. a false connection or bleeding of channels. Quite unexpected though and not something I'd consider a feature of "a bad quality mixer".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a phasing issue between radio mics ?